# PHP code not working properly, can't find syntax error

Tags: php, html, wamp

I have an html page with some very basic php in it. I have no idea why it is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="author" content="Robin Van Campen">
    <meta name="description" content="Website showing XSS and HMAC" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="html, security "/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css" />
    <link href="Resources/Icons/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Example 2</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <?php
        echo "<p>name</p>";
    ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I load that page from clicking on a form button, I get this on the screen.

```
name
"; ?>
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is your document file .php or .html ?

Comment: using **PHP** in a **HTML** file ? what is your server configuration ?

Comment: *"PHP code not working properly"* --- More like ***"PHP not installed or configured properly"*** --- PHP has done its job. Consult other comments/answers which is the most likely case.

Comment: It is weird because most browsers will comment out unprocessed PHP code.

Comment: Sidenote: You can run `.html` files as PHP, you just need to instruct Apache to do so. Google "how to run html files as PHP" and you will find results; call it a *learning curve*. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the file .php instead of .html or configure your server to parse .html files.

Comment: thanks this was the problem, the tutorial I followed however did not say it needed to be a php extension. thank you I will green mark the question as soon as the timer expires.

Answer (score 3):

Is your file extension set to PHP?  It looks like you are just adding php to a html file.  You need to have PHP set as the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Your file has to be a PHP extension ie: myFile.php and also it has to be uploaded to your server before it will process since PHP pre-processor is serverside.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save your file with extension .php
2. What server you are using?
   Apache
   Wamp
   Lamp
   Can process php pages on the go

If your using IIS for windows you require to install php extension

1. If you have hosted your page somewhere check if your host provides php support